# CSS horizontally center a div

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a very simple layout that I am trying to achieve in CSS, but I am not having any luck.  All I want to do is (horizontally) center a div that contains a link.  **The size of the div should be based on the size of its content**.

I have tried a bunch of combinations of auto margins, text alignments, and display types, but can't seem to figure it out (I am a CSS noob).  I have cooked up a very simple case (and the best I can do)

HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="myDiv">
        <a href="google.com">google.com</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiv
{
    background:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.myDiv a
{
     text-decoration:none;
}
```

I have made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VvL6M/) as well.  Is this type of layout possible without complicated HTML/CSS /hacks?

Comment: change your magins to be margin: 0 40%; that works great for the demo.

Comment: auto margins only work when a specific value for the div's width is given. You could just apply your styles to the anchor tag itself.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, please read the question.

Comment: This *is* a duplicate, about a hundred times over. What you're seeing below is well-trodden ground.

Comment: @isherwood You are correct, this is a duplicate question, and I have also voted to close it.  I am completely new to CSS so I got confused and thought the cases were different for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can do this:

```
.myDiv
  {
   display:table;
   margin:auto;
  }
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/VvL6M/9/**

Comment: Aah, good ol' table to the rescue!

Comment: It works, but I'd call this a last resort. There's usually no need to make divs act like tables.

Comment: In anyway to do this you still need to change the display for the div ..... and this avoid the style for any parent like display:inline-block needs

Answer (score 0):

Why not just apply the styles to the anchor tag itself;
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VvL6M/3/)

```
.myDiv {
    text-align:center;
}
.myDiv a {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:lightblue;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Because of clipping:  http://jsfiddle.net/u4PAs/

Comment: Inline-block on the a fixes that: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/u4PAs/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#container
{
    text-align:center;
}
.myDiv
{
    background:lightblue;
    display:inline;
}

.myDiv a
{
     text-decoration:none;
}
```

And:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="myDiv">
            <a href="google.com">google.com</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Check out this JFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VvL6M/11/

Comment: My bad- See new url above